# How can I save another object with its own form but in the form of the first one?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, forms

I know that it's not valid to do 'form in form' because of HTML specification.

So, my problem: There is, for example, Car model and it's form which I've created with the help of Form Object (it has a lot of additional info).
But there is one place in my form where I need to put elements dynamically. Adding wheels, for example. Each wheel has it's own parameters. The flow is such: I fill the fields of addition wheel's form, touch the 'ADD WHEEL' button and the new one wheel added to the my main form.

So, you can see that there are two separate buttons, but the main form is one.
How can I achieve this in Rails way?

!My solution: Add not the specific form but just specific fields for wheel, and process this only with JS and AJAX. I click the button -> jQuery catchs data from this specific fields -> Sends Ajax request for new wheel creation -> return an html of created wheel.
Is it thes correct way?

Comment: You're on the right path with the AJAX approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `accepts_nested_attributes_for` like this:

```
class Car < ActiveRecord::Base    
  has_many :wheels, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :seats, dependent: :destroy

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :wheels, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :seats, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true
end
```

[image]

Comment: What about the separate button? As i know, nested_attrributes beign saved while the main object is saved

Comment: Alex as I understood the wheels always belong to a given car. So I think for saving that's okay. Or am I mistaken? For the add/remove button you can use cocoon gem.

Comment: I added a pic how I use it in one of my apps. Product form with product_competition and produc_usecase as nested attr.

Comment: Thank you.
What if I wat to handle adding/removing with ajax?

Comment: I'm doing it with cocoon gem